# Cannot share internet over usb to rasp zero with RNDIS on mac, when RP is connected I lose internet connection on my mac

Tags: pi-zero, macos

I've been trying to connect my raspberry pi zero over the internet with RNDIS on a mac.

And while it seems very easy on every tutorial, it doesn't work for me.

I will share a few screenshots so you can understand my configuration.
[image]

[image]

[image]

So I been able to shh into it and to do some configuration following this tuto

[Revisiting the Raspberry Pi Zero WiFi Hacking Gadget](https://thesmashy.medium.com/revisiting-the-raspberry-pi-zero-wifi-hacking-gadget-e407b38a2fcf)

and this one

[Turning your Raspberry Pi Zero into a USB Gadget](https://learn.adafruit.com/turning-your-raspberry-pi-zero-into-a-usb-gadget/ethernet-gadget)

Because the configuration on tuto didn't work, I started using a different numbers but the idea is the same.

/etc/resolv.conf :

`nameserver 8.8.8.8` (also tried with my router address 192.168.0.1)

/etc/network/interfaces :

```
allow-hotplug usb0
iface usb0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.15
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.0.0
    broadcast 192.168.0.255
    gateway 192.168.0.1
```

So this is where I am.

As for now, I cannot connect through ssh anymore no idea why.
Something I noticed is while I give it a static IP and while I'm being able to ssh into it, I lose my internet connection on my laptop which I find very weird. Isn't is supposed to share internet?

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, undo all your changes to `/etc/network/interfaces` - if you're making changes here you are following old tutorials (as one of your links suggests) - I wouldn't say never touch anything here, but only do so if you are 100% sure you know what you are doing

Now, edit `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` and add the following

```
interface usb0
static ip_address=192.168.0.15/24
static routers=192.168.0.1
static domain_name_servers=8.8.8.8 (or whatever is appropriate to your needs)
```

This does assume your MAC is set up correctly with IP address 192.168.0.1 for the RNDIS interface - but you've shown nothing regarding that, so I'm speculating that isn't also an issue

Comment: Thanks for the answer, about the router address it was my actual internet router address so it was not good but I found my Mac IP address, well I think I have. 
I can ping the pi when I manually give the static ip but cannot ssh into it.
With automatic DHCP though, I have now access to internet. I'm not sure to understand what happened here but I will accept this outcome and look more about network configuration, I bought this pi for this after all !

Comment: as stated, the "router address" is the MACs RNDIS ip address ***This does assume your MAC is set up correctly with IP address 192.168.0.1 for the RNDIS interface***